# SQL Errror en group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos estoy tratando de correr el siguente query

```
select
x.[Nombre de empleado],x.[Sueldo diario],x.[Sueldo integrado],x.Total,x.conteo
from(
select
    em.nombreLargo [Nombre de empleado],
    em.sueldoDiario [Sueldo diario],
    em.sueldoIntegrado [Sueldo integrado],
    count(distinct convert(varchar,bi.FechaVerificacion,111)) conteo ,
    CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) + 
    CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) [Total]
    --COUNT(bi.FechaVerificacion) [días laborados]

    from 
    sysCPEmpleados ce 
    inner join  sysCPCentroCosto cc on 
    ce.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto 
    and
    ce.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleados em on
    em.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle bi on
    bi.idSysCPEmpleados = ce.idSysCPEmpleados


    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto ='SBIB15C'          
    --and em.idSysCPPuestos = @idPuestos
    and em.idEstatus = 2
    ) as x
group by x.[Nombre de empleado],x.[Sueldo diario],x.[Sueldo integrado],x.conteo,x.Total
```

, pero no sé porque me manda este error:

> Column 'sysCPEmpleados.nombreLargo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Alguien podría decirme que es lo que me está fallando?

Comment: Cuando usas Count(), y traes mas registros ademas de ese, necesitas agrupar los demás registros, osea necesitas un Group By dentro de "x".

Comment: @Ricardo súper, sube una respuest ay te la doy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas Count(), y traes mas registros ademas de ese, necesitas agrupar los demás registros, osea necesitas un Group By dentro de "x":

```
select
x.[Nombre de empleado],x.[Sueldo diario],x.[Sueldo integrado],x.Total,x.conteo
from(
select
    em.nombreLargo [Nombre de empleado],
    em.sueldoDiario [Sueldo diario],
    em.sueldoIntegrado [Sueldo integrado],
    count(distinct convert(varchar,bi.FechaVerificacion,111)) conteo ,
    CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) + 
    CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) [Total]
    --COUNT(bi.FechaVerificacion) [días laborados]

    from 
    sysCPEmpleados ce 
    inner join  sysCPCentroCosto cc on 
    ce.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto 
    and
    ce.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleados em on
    em.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle bi on
    bi.idSysCPEmpleados = ce.idSysCPEmpleados


    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto ='SBIB15C'          
    --and em.idSysCPPuestos = @idPuestos
    and em.idEstatus = 2
    group by em.nombreLargo,em.sueldoDiario,em.sueldoIntegrado
    ) as x
group by x.[Nombre de empleado],x.[Sueldo diario],x.[Sueldo integrado],x.conteo,x.Total
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes agrupar los campos que estan dentro de la subconsulta para que tu codigo funcione, tu codigo deberia quedar asi espero que te funcione,

```
select
    x.[Nombre de empleado],
    x.[Sueldo diario],
    x.[Sueldo integrado],
    x.Total,
    x.conteo
from(
select
    em.nombreLargo [Nombre de empleado],
    em.sueldoDiario [Sueldo diario],
    em.sueldoIntegrado [Sueldo integrado],
    count(distinct convert(varchar,bi.FechaVerificacion,111)) conteo ,
    CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) + 
    CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) [Total]
    from sysCPEmpleados ce 
    inner join  sysCPCentroCosto cc on ce.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto 
    and ce.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas inner join sysCPEmpleados em on
    em.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas inner join sysCPEmpleadosBiometricoDetalle bi on
    bi.idSysCPEmpleados = ce.idSysCPEmpleados
    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto ='SBIB15C'          
    and em.idEstatus = 2
    group by em.nombreLargo, em.sueldoDiario, em.sueldoIntegrado 
    ) as x
group by x.[Nombre de empleado],x.[Sueldo diario],x.[Sueldo integrado],x.conteo,x.Total
```